# How to solve TinyMce image manager Network Error

Tags: codeigniter, plugins, editor, tinymce, http-status-code-404

It was working until my hosting do some changes to server. I don't know what changes they have made.

request is: [click here](http://mysite.com/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/js/compressor.php?classes=mox.Event,mox.List,mox.DOM,mox.geom.Point,mox.geom.Rect,mox.String,mox.dom.Drag,mox.tpl.Template,mox.tpl.Paging,mox.data.ResultSet,mox.net.Cookie,mox.ui.WindowManager,mox.ui.Menu,mox.ui.MenuItem,mox.ui.DropMenu,mox.ui.DropMenuItem,mox.dom.Layer,mox.dom.Tween,mox.net.JSON,mox.dom.Form,mox.util.Dispatcher,moxiecode.manager.BaseManager,moxiecode.manager.ImageManager,moxiecode.manager.DevKit)

or

http://mysite.com/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/js/compressor.php?classes=mox.Event,mox.List,mox.DOM,mox.geom.Point,mox.geom.Rect,mox.String,mox.dom.Drag,mox.tpl.Template,mox.tpl.Paging,mox.data.ResultSet,mox.net.Cookie,mox.ui.WindowManager,mox.ui.Menu,mox.ui.MenuItem,mox.ui.DropMenu,mox.ui.DropMenuItem,mox.dom.Layer,mox.dom.Tween,mox.net.JSON,mox.dom.Form,mox.util.Dispatcher,moxiecode.manager.BaseManager,moxiecode.manager.ImageManager,moxiecode.manager.DevKit

it returns NetworkError: 404 Not Found

if i remove mox.net.Cookie and mox.net.JSON by hand from the querystring it works.

What should be the problem? How can i solve it.

I use CodeIgniter.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked existence AND read permissions on those mox.net files including (if any) any cache/write directory?

Comment: if it works in local, then try to change $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; to other options in config.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .htaccess it may be possible you're heading to a CI controller rather than the file you're looking for.

Here is an example mod_rewrite rule that might help.  Often it's worth checking your access log to see which file is being called also.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|media|favicon\.ico|ipadicon\.jpg|tiny_mce)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```